# Use a list comprehension to concatenate each item in list to a substring and store as a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I want to use a list comprehension to concatenate the strings in `metadata.index.to_list()` to the `: set()` substring and store them as `` dictionary. The length of the list is **undefined** and the following is just an example.

My attempt:

```
uuids_to_zarr_files = dict([uuid + ": set()" for uuid in metadata.index.to_list()])
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [29], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 uuids_to_zarr_files = dict([uuid + ": set()" for uuid in metadata.index.to_list()])

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 39; 2 is required
```

Input:

`metadata.index.to_list()`

```
['07317dfade92994d6fbbe9faef1236f7',
 '91890e05edbd0a767092e10502b3ea99',
 '56b00177fa2bbd091a10dae8d57c9539']
```

Expected output:

```
uuids_to_zarr_files = {'07317dfade92994d6fbbe9faef1236f7': set(), '91890e05edbd0a767092e10502b3ea99': set(), '56b00177fa2bbd091a10dae8d57c9539': set()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You list comprehension does what you want it to do.

However, why do you think `dict(["07317dfade92994d6fbbe9faef1236f7: set()"])`
should do anything but raise an error? Do you expect the `dict` constructor to understand your own bespoke format? Here is the docs for what the `dict` constructor expects:

```
class dict(object)
 |  dict() -> new empty dictionary
 |  dict(mapping) -> new dictionary initialized from a mapping object's
 |      (key, value) pairs
 |  dict(iterable) -> new dictionary initialized as if via:
 |      d = {}
 |      for k, v in iterable:
 |          d[k] = v
 |  dict(**kwargs) -> new dictionary initialized with the name=value pairs
 |      in the keyword argument list.  For example:  dict(one=1, two=2)
 |
```

You provide it an iterable, but it expects an iterable of key-value pairs. But you provided an iterable of strings.

But you should just use a dictionary comprehension here:

```
{uuid: set() for uuid in metadata.index.to_list()}
```

If you want to see how you could use the `dict` constructor, you could do:

```
dict([(uuid, set()) for uuid in metadata.index.to_list()])
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do your job , here we have utilized dictionary comprehension

```
metadata = ['07317dfade92994d6fbbe9faef1236f7',
            '91890e05edbd0a767092e10502b3ea99',
            '56b00177fa2bbd091a10dae8d57c9539']

uuids_to_zarr_files = {uuid: set() for uuid in metadata}

print(uuids_to_zarr_files)
```

Output:

```
{'07317dfade92994d6fbbe9faef1236f7': set(), '91890e05edbd0a767092e10502b3ea99': set(), '56b00177fa2bbd091a10dae8d57c9539': set()}
```